# why these two lists are not equal?

Tags: java, list, equals

I was ask this java question in an interview:

```
    List a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(a);

    List b = new ArrayList();
    b.add(b);

    if (a.equals(b)) {
        System.out.println("equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("non-equal");
    }
```

why the result is 'non-equal' ? thanks!

Comment: In it's current form, your code doesn't result in `non-equal`.  It results in a `StackOverflowException`. Why?  Now that would be a good interview question. :)

Comment: Was it supposed to be `b.add(b)` or `a.add(b)`? In the actual interview, what was it? Because if the interviewer said the correct output was `non-equal`, then it was not a typo and you needn't edit the question - in which case Emd4600 has the correct answer. If the interviewer just said "What's the result here?" and it *was* `b.add(b)`, then it was a trick  question and Andreas has the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code (after the edit) results in `StackOverflowException` because `a` contains itself and `b` contains itself.

`a.equals(b)` will iterate the lists in parallel and compare each element, so `a.get(0).equals(b.get(0))`, but `a.get(0)` is `a` and `b.get(0)` is `b` and comparing those will recurse the `equals` method, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 2):

```
List a = new ArrayList();
a.add(a);

List b = new ArrayList();
a.add(b);
```

Look carefully. a has now two items (a and b) and b has no items. So a is not equal to b.

Comment: It's a typo, but checking for equality with `b.add(b)` would actually cause a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

[THIS ANSWER REFERS TO THE POST BEFORE THE EDIT]

The `.equals` method compares the content of the two array lists. (Not if they are the same object)

If you look carefully after you use the method `.add`, the List `a` has two elements (`a` and `b`), instead of `b` which has nothing

The code doesn't go in `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, because the `.equals` method checks first the size of the two lists, and then the content.

In fact if you try this code:

```
    List a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(a);
    List b = new ArrayList();
    b.add(b); // <-watch carefully here. Now a and b are of the same size
    if (a.equals(b)) { // checks the size first, then the objects in the lists
        System.out.println("equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("non-equal");
    }
```

you get the `java.lang.StackOverflowError`